# How to find the MapR distribution version

Tags: hadoop, mapr

The client has the some MapR distribution installed at there. I want to do some analysis on it. So I want to found the version of the MapR distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cat /opt/mapr/MapRBuildVersion`